# Copy constructor of thrown object throws - why thrown object is still thrown?

Tags: c++, exception

Mind the following code:

```
struct exception_in_copy_constructor
{
    exception_in_copy_constructor() = default;
    ~exception_in_copy_constructor() = default;
    exception_in_copy_constructor(const exception_in_copy_constructor& other) 
    { 
        throw std::exception(":-(");
    }
};
```

Now, it is clear that when I throw this object, an std::exception will be thrown.

So lets look at the following code:

```
try
{    
    exception_in_copy_constructor ecc;
    throw ecc;
}
catch(exception_in_copy_constructor& ecc)
{
    printf("IN exception_in_copy_constructor&\r\n");
}
catch(std::exception& ex)
{
    printf("IN std::exception&\r\n");
}
```

I would expect the before ecc would be thrown, an std::exception will be thrown, and because of that, ecc will never be thrown. The code above confirmed that by printing "IN std::exception&"

**BUT** mind this code:

```
try
{    
    exception_in_copy_constructor ecc;
    throw ecc;
}
catch(exception_in_copy_constructor& ecc)
{
    printf("IN exception_in_copy_constructor&\r\n");
}
```

I would expect that **nothing** will get caught, but to my surprise,  `catch(exception_in_copy_constructor& ecc)` caught the exception (?!?!)

Can anyone explain what is going on?

I am using VS2015

Thanks!

EDIT: Users wrote they cannot reproduce, so I am writing the whole code as it is on my computer.
Also, I am using VS2015, debug, x64 (It also reproduce in release).

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    struct exception_in_copy_constructor
    {
        exception_in_copy_constructor() = default;
        ~exception_in_copy_constructor() = default;
        exception_in_copy_constructor(const exception_in_copy_constructor& other)
        {
            throw std::exception(":-(");
        }
    };

    try
    {
        exception_in_copy_constructor ecc;
        throw ecc;
    }
    catch(exception_in_copy_constructor&)
    {
        printf("We will never get here!\r\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Copy elision is going on.

Comment: [The Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#:exception_handling,exception_object) doesn't seem to say what should happen when the exception objects copy constructor throws, which is weird. Maybe it is said somewhere else?

Comment: @Rakete1111 The standard doesn't spell out that exception handling is the same for each individual way in which functions get called. That would just be a waste of time. The normal rules for exceptions apply here.

Comment: The described behaviour is not reproducible on http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual. Are you sure your test is right? It wouldn't make sense for copy elision to take place for only one of these, it suggests there's some other difference as well.

Comment: @hvd I can confirm your findings for clang, gcc (on O0, O2 and O3), as well as VC++ 2017 for x86, x64, with and without optimizations, so unless it's a particular issue with VC++ 2015, there's probably something else going on.

Comment: @hvf - I will edit the question and place the whole code exactly as it is.

Comment: I found the problem! I am ashamed to say it was completely my mistake. I ran it with a debugger, and the unhandled exception dialog did go up, but I clicked on continue, which simply ignored the abort! :-(

SORRY